# How many times is data copied in a C++ AMP array?

Tags: c++, c++-amp

The `default_cpu_access_type` property for my accelerator is `access_type_read_write`. Let's say I run this:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Concurrency::array<int, 1> a { 4, v.begin(), v.end() };
parallel_for_each(a.extent, [=, &a](Concurrency::index<1> i) restrict(amp) { ++a[i]; });
for (int i { 0 }; i < 4; ++i) std::cout << a[i] << " ";
```

How many times are my four ints copied? Are they copied in RAM when the `Concurrency::array` is constructed? Are they copied again when the `parallel_for_each` loop begins, or does my graphics card somehow use the data in RAM? What if I use `array_view` instead of `array` - does that save a copy?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is one transfer from CPU to GPU when you declare the array and initialize it.

Then you can use it freely on the GPU side (inside the parallel_for_each loop).
Array to do not contain auto-synchronisation mechanism for data so I'm not certain of what happens when you pick a value in your for loop.

If you choose array_view the synchronisation of data is implicit. One copy will happened at initialisation and one to bring data back from GPU to CPU when you pick a value.

I recommend you this blog post http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/array-And-Arrayview-From-Amph.aspx or even the complete serie on amp.

Comment: I now believe that my final line of code involves no copies, since the CPU is sharing memory with the accelerator. Also, I think you're wrong that data is copied when array_view is initialised - it's copied to the accelerator in an ad hoc way as needed, and the data in the underlying vector is updated before my last line of code is executed.